# Suitable algorithm for combinations of numbers in an array

Tags: php

I have a PHP project where I need to work out all of the combinations of an indeterminate amount of numbers (stored in an array) (but usually no greater than 5) and store them in a separate array.

e.g. (not using PHP syntax):

```
numbers = (1 2 3)

1 + 2 = 3

1 + 3 = 4

2 + 3 = 5

1 + 2 + 3 = 6
```

which would create an array of:

```
3,4,5,6
```

A second example would be:

```
numbers = 1 2 3 4

1 + 2 = 3
1 + 3 = 4
1 + 4 = 5
1 + 2 + 3 = 6
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10
2 + 3 = 5
2 + 4 = 6
2 + 3 + 4 = 9
3 + 4 = 7
```

I have tried modifying the code found at: https://r.je/php-find-every-combination.html

but I seem to be not be getting the correct output, this is my reduced code without pushing to an array:

```
$nums = array(1, 2, 3);   

$num = count($nums); 

$total = pow(2, $num);

$test = 0;


for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {  

    //For each combination check if each bit is set 

    for ($j = 0; $j < $num; $j++) { 

       //Is bit $j set in $i?


        if (pow(2, $j) & $i) {

          $test += $nums[$j];


        }

    } 
    echo $test . ',';

}
```

This outputs: `0,1,3,6,9,13,18,24,`

If anyone knows of a good method of achieving this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the ouput you are getting ? Show it with your question

Comment: Thanks - I've now added that.

Comment: In plain English: Do you want each element of the array to be added with other each element and store results in new array?

Comment: All unique combinations of numbers to be added to each other and stored in a new array.

Comment: @user319940 To make more clarification supply more examples in your question.

Comment: I have added a second example.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your for, put your `$test` var to 0

```
$nums = array(1, 2, 3);   

$num = count($nums); 

$total = pow(2, $num);

$test = 0;


for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {  

    //For each combination check if each bit is set 

    for ($j = 0; $j < $num; $j++) { 

       //Is bit $j set in $i?


        if (pow(2, $j) & $i) {

          $test += $nums[$j];


        }

    } 
    echo $test . ',';
    $test = 0;

}
```

**[EDIT]**

mmm... minus 0, this is the result:

```
0, 1(1), 2(2), 3(3), 3(1+2), 4(1+3), 5(2+3), 6(1+2+3),
```

Comment: The output in this case doesn't seem quite right:  0,1,2,3,3,4,5,6, - thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: @user319940 this correspond to the example you based on, But what do you want is only addition between two values ?

Comment: It should be able to cope with more than two e.g. 1 + 2 + 3 = 6. I'm trying to get all of the unique combinations of numbers to be added to each other and stored in a new array.

Comment: @user319940 Then this result is good (minus 0) , I can read 1, 2, 3, 1+2, 1+3, 2+3 and 1+2+3 here

Answer (score 0):

This approach should hopefully fulfill your request. It sums up all possible combinations without repetitions recursively and creates another `array` that contains the "combination-equations" as `keys` and the corresponding results as `values`. So that it's easier to see of how one result is calculated.

```
$nums = array(1,2,3,4);

function find_comb($arr){
    // one number left (no combination), so return an empty array
    if(count($arr)<2)return array();
    $sum = array_reduce($arr, function($prev,$curr){
        return $prev + $curr;
    },0);
    $equa = implode("+",$arr);
    return array_merge(
            // 1+2+3+4
            array($equa => $sum),
            // 1+4
            count($arr) > 2 ? array($arr[0]."+".$arr[count($arr)-1] => $arr[0]+$arr[count($arr)-1]) : array(),
            // 1+2+3, 1+2 ...
            find_comb(array_slice($arr,0, count($arr)-1)),
            // 2+3+4, 3+4 ...
            find_comb(array_slice($arr,1))
    );
}

$allCombs = find_comb($nums);

var_dump($allCombs);
```

Hope this helps you.